# How to display multiple words in string without readline using c++?

Tags: c++

I'm using Visual C++ 6.0 and currently created a program that will print the output stored in string.

The problem is when I entered words with space, only the first word is visible in the output.

Example:

```
Enter your address: new york
new
Press any key to continue
```

I want this:

```
Enter your address: new york
new york
Press any key to continue
```

Also, I tried to use `getline` but when I entered words, It will first print blank space then stored the last output before the current one.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
  string address1;
  cout<<"Enter your address:";
  cin>> address1;
  // getline(cin, address1); code when using getline
  cout<<address1<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: `getline` is the correct method. If you had problems using it, show the code for that.

Comment: The input operator `>>` reads only space-delimited "words".

Comment: see, I put the getline code in my question

Comment: It is best habbit to write int main() instead of void main() in c++ programming

Comment: @Pkboss it's not just "best habit", it is mandatory.

Comment: *"It will first print blank space then stored the last output before the current one."* -- I have no idea what this means. In fact I'm quite certain that it is nonsense. Please illustrate it.

Comment: Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455802/how-to-read-a-complete-line-from-the-user-using-cin

Comment: this is just a sample. int main() is mandatory

Comment: when you tried getline, did you remove the cin>> line?

Comment: Visual Studio 6? in 2014, seriously? it's from 1998

Comment: Well, actually the system was created in Visual Studio 6.0 and we are about to renew the system using C#. To be able to do that, we need to know C++ for us to understand the flow of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it correct, but the main problem is that you are using `cin` while you should avoid it and use `getline(cin,address1)`  because `cin` will only take a single word and it will not take anyhting which you type after space. On the other hand `getline(cin,address1)`  can take a complete sentence along with spaces

Read the comments and use this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()//using int main()
{

  string address1;

  cout<<"Enter your address:";

  //cin>> address1; Don't use it

  getline(cin, address1);//use this

  cout<<address1<<"\n";

  return 0;//returning an integer 0
}
```

Comment: yes, it displays the whole words, but the problem is that when I enter "new york", it will first print extra space below then enter again to see the results. It always need to double click the enter before it shows the result.

Comment: Copy my code in your compiler and run it. After typing "new york" you should press enter once and "new york" will be printed in the next line. If problem continues then try it on a different compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::getline (std::cin, address1);`, not cin. Because `cin` takes space as delimiter.

Comment: yes, it displays the whole words, but the problem is that when I enter "new york", it will first print extra space below then enter again to see the results. It always need to double click the enter before it shows the result.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one? Kind of getline concept, presuming newline character is '\n', change as required according to your platform, unix or windows etc

```
int main()
{
  string addrpart, address1;
  cout<<"Enter your address:";
  cin>> addrpart;
  while (addrpart != "x") {
    address1 += addrpart + " ";
    addrpart = "x";
    cin>> addrpart;
  }
  cout<<address1<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: yes, it displays the whole words, but the problem is that when I enter "new york", it will first print extra space below then enter again to see the results. It always need to double click the enter before it shows the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  string userinput;

  cout << "Enter your address:";
  getline ( cin, userinput );
  cout << userinput;

  return 0;
}

$ g++ a.cpp -o app
$ ./app
Enter your address:new york
new york
```

Comment: yes, it displays the whole words, but the problem is that when I enter "new york", it will first print extra space below then enter again to see the results. It always need to double click the enter before it shows the result.