# How do I make a string vector keep spaces from user input?

Tags: c++

I do apologize if this has been asked before, but I haven't really seen this come up in my books or in other examples. So here I go.

I have been getting into a card game, after getting lazy with constant shuffling I made a program that does it for me, theoretically. I realize there are already programs that do so, but where is the fun in that? Onto the problem that led to the question. Whenever I typed in a card with a two or more word name, it chopped off all the words but the first. I have known this to happen but I don't know how to fix it normally. Let alone how to store "A, the C" in a vector and keep spaces.

**The Question:** How do I store a string like "A, the C" in a string and put it in a container and be able to retrieve it with the spaces in tact? Am I doing something wrong in the code, or am I using the wrong tool for the shed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string example = " ";
cin >> example; //typed eggs and milk, only got eggs
cout << example << endl;

}
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with vectors in particular. Please keep simplifying your problem until it's [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @chris it's been re-edited in a simple fashion that still reproduces the final product.

Comment: string example = "";
getline(cin, example);

found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455802/how-to-read-a-complete-line-from-the-user-using-cin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
cin >> example;
```

use

```
std::getline(std::cin, example);
```

`cin >> example;` will stop reading when it finds a white space. `std::getline` will cotinue reading until a specified delimiter (`'\n'` by default) is found.

[More on `std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).