# Accept Empty Character Space in String

Tags: c++

I am trying to have a string accept a character space. However when you type something like:

**Mike Smith**

the output is only

**Mike**

Is there an easy way to fix this?
Can I do something like:

**string playerName (50)** <-- Where (50) is the length of the string

My Code below:

```
int main() {
string playerName;
cout << "Enter Player Name: ";
    cin >> playerName;

cout << playerName << endl;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a complete line from the user using cin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455802/how-to-read-a-complete-line-from-the-user-using-cin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to read a whole line of input:

```
getline(cin, playerName);
```

Comment: So instead of: cin >> playerName use getline(cin, playerName) in it's place?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
getline(cin, playerName);
```

But remember, you have to use the following line before getting any other data type after using the above line.

```
cin.ignore();
```

Comment: What if I wanted to display 2 players names? Does it just forget the first one?

Comment: Is there another way without having to use getline? Can I just specify the length of the string?

Comment: Just wrap your `cout`'s and `cin` with a for loop

Comment: You can do it in `c` with `scanf`, but I don't know whether there exists the same in `c++` or not.

Comment: @MoreOutdoors What happens if someone's name contains 3 words and the next person's name contains 1 word? How do you tell which belongs to which player?

Comment: @MoreOutdoors Hey! don't take credit! I +1 your question, that's why you got chance to vote ;)