# How do I add a string to my array of type struct which contains both strings and ints in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

These are my Structs:

```
struct Artist
{
    string Name;
    string CountryOfOrigin;

};

struct Time
{
    int Minutes;
    int Seconds;
};

struct Song
{
    string Title;
    Artist ArtistDetails;
    Time LengthOfSong;
};
```

And my Function:

```
void LoadSongDataFromFile(Song s[])
{
    string inputFile, title, name, country;
    int minutes, seconds;
    cout << "Please enter the input file name: ";
    cin >> inputFile;

ifstream input;
input.open(inputFile);

int count = 0;
while (input >> title)
{
    s[count].Title >> title;
    s[count].ArtistDetails.Name >> name;
    s[count].ArtistDetails.CountryOfOrigin >> country;
    s[count].LengthOfSong.Minutes >> minutes;
    s[count].LengthOfSong.Seconds >> seconds;

    count++;
}
```

}

I'm getting an error in these three lines:

```
    s[count].Title >> title;
    s[count].ArtistDetails.Name >> name;
    s[count].ArtistDetails.CountryOfOrigin >> country;
```

Saying no operator >> matches these opperands.
Opperand types are: std::string >> std::string

Also the data I'm trying to put into the struct array comes from a text file which contains this information:

Perfect

Ed Sheeran with Beyonce

England

4

23

The text file name is songdata.txt if that matters. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=` operator to assign values.

```
input >> minutes;
s[count].LengthOfSong.Minutes = minutes;
```

Or read directly into the struct:

```
input >> s[count].LengthOfSong.Minutes;
```

Reading with `>>` reads one word from the input, so it will only work with your numbers. To read a complete line (the strings), use [std::getline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455802/how-to-read-a-complete-line-from-the-user-using-cin).

Answer (score 0):

The `>>` operator has two meanings:

- shift bits around
- read input from a stream into an object

The latter meaning is used here. As you see, the definition says "from a stream" and "to an object".

In your code you call the `>>` operator to read "from a string" `s[count].Title` to another string `title`.

There are many variants for the predefined `>>` operator. They all have a stream as the first operand. Therefore, to use them, use `std::cin >> s[count].Title`.

As mentioned in the other answer, the `>>` operator stops copying after the first word. Therefore it's better to use `std::getline(std::cin, s[count].Title)`.