# C++ Convert filename input redirection to new output text file with .txt appended to name of new output file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, io-redirection, argv

I am trying to use input redirection to scan a file for regular expressions and output those regular expressions with the line number of the file to a new output text file.  The output text file is to be the name of the file that was used for the input redirection with ".txt" appended to it.  For instance if the program was run as follows:

> ./scanRegex < scanThisFile.log

Then the output file should be called

> scanThisFile.log.txt

I created a simple program as follows ( minus the regex scanning to
isolate the issue ).

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <ios>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
    {
       std::string fileName = argv[1]; //<---===== ??????
       std::string txt = ".txt\n";
       char outputFile[100];

       for( int i = 0; i < fileName.length(); ++i ){
         outputFile[i] = fileName[i];
       }
       for( int i = fileName.length(); i < fileName.length() + 4; ++i ){
         outputFile[i] = txt[i - fileName.length()];
       }

       std::ofstream outfile;
       outfile.open(outputFile);

       outfile << "It works!!";

       outfile.close();
    }
```

When I use

> argv[ 0 ]

the program runs but the filename is wrong for what my intention is but is understandable because the program name is the first argument for argv:
a.txt

When I use

> argv[ 1 ]

I get the following runtime error:

> osboxes@osboxes:~/Desktop/ps7$ ./a < device1_intouch.log
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>   what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
>   Aborted (core dumped)

When I use

> argv[2]

the program runs but the filename is wrong and full of gibberish (overflow?):

Maybe this is only part of where my problem is.  Any help would be
greatly
appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: There is a big difference between _command line arguments_ and the _standard input_. `argv` is for command line arguments, while `std::cin` is for standard input. Also note that you should always check `argc`, which is the number of elements in `argv` before you read from `argv`, to avoid undefined behavior (aka "bugs").

Comment: When you _invoke_ your program as in `$ ./myProgram arg1 arg2 .. argn`, that translates to `argv == {"/path/to/myProgram", "arg1", "arg2", ..., "argn"}` and `argc == n` when your `main` function is called. This has nothing to do with the standard input, which you read via `std::cin`, and which may be supplied during, not just before, the call to `main`

Comment: I understand.. for some reason I thought that anything inputted on the command line got assigned to argv ( including standard input ).  I guess I will just have to change my program to accept the file as a command line argument rather than use input redirection.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the *standard input* with your program's *command line arguments*. Command line arguments are the list of strings that you include on the command line when you invoke your program. For example:

> `$ ./myProgram arg1 arg2 ... argn`

These are read via `argv` and `argc`, which respectively represent the "argument vector" and "argument count." By convention, the first argument is the working directory of your program. In this example, you would have:

```
argv == {"/path/to/myProgram", "arg1", "arg2", ..., "argn"}
argc == n
```

at the start of `main`. You must be careful not to read from `argv` out of bounds by checking `argc`, as with any raw array.

The *standard input*, on the other hand, is a *stream* of data that is supplied to your program *throughout* the call to `main`. This is read using `std::cin`.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s; // read from standard input
}
```

When you run this program, it will block at the indicated line until it recieves data from the standard input. This data can be supplied by typing manually while the program is running from the command line:

> `$ ./myProgram`
>
> `hello`

or by input redirection:

> `$ echo "hello" | ./myProgram`
>
> `$ ./myProgram < hello.txt`

In the three examples above, `s` will contain the first word of text from the input, and you can use it for whatever you want on the following line.

Note that `std::cin >> s` will read text until it reaches the first white-space character. Fortunately, there are easy ways to [read an entire line from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455802/how-to-read-a-complete-line-from-the-user-using-cin) and to [read everything from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c/36978839)