# While loop bug with cout and cin in c++? or is it

Tags: c++, while-loop, cout

So basically I was making a chat app and then I came across to a bug i couldnt fix. for purpose of not leaking my source code here is an example of it:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        string lol;
        cout << "you say >> ";
        cin >> lol;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so the bug is when you type a space in cin like
 you type: "hi lol" it prints "you say >>"
 twice and the more space you 
put the more "you say >>" repeats I really dont understand why this is happening. can soemone help me?

Comment: See [How to read a complete line from the user using cin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455802/how-to-read-a-complete-line-from-the-user-using-cin)

Comment: `cin >> lol` is skipping all white space, compare https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt.

Comment: So, basically, have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838711/stdcin-input-with-spaces) that explains how to treat whitespace in `cin()`?

Comment: FYI, you declare a new instance of the string at the top of the while loop and don't every print the value of `lol`.

Comment: thanks guys i fixed it: ```#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        static char lol[128];
        cout << "you say >> ";
        cin.getline(lol,256);
        cout << lol << endl;;
    }
    return 0;
}```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's no bug, that's [the way it works](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).

The `operator>>()` for `std::string` separates by whitespace, so you effectively get one word at a time.

If you'd like to read an entire line, use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: what is the syntax of std::getline()?

Comment: getline is a function, it has the same syntax as any other function call.