# String doesn't save spaces?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am making something where you have to put your name but my string doesn't save the spaces, why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string name;
int main()
{
  cout<<"<System>: Please enter your name"<<endl;
  cin>>name;
  cout<<name;
return 0;
}
```

I entered:

> Test 123

And I got:

> Test

Comment: `cin>>name;` reads only until the next space. That's just how it is defined to work. [Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a complete line from the user using cin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455802/how-to-read-a-complete-line-from-the-user-using-cin)

Answer (score 5):

the insertion operator inserts only the first string (before any whitespace)  from `std::cin` to the string if you want to take the whole line use `std::getline()`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string name;
int main()
{
  cout<<"<System>: Please enter your name"<<endl;
  std::getline(std::cin, name);
  cout<<name;
return 0;
}
```

And see this [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin <<` only reads up to the next space (ie. space, tabulation or line break). If you want to read the whole line, you will have to use `std::getline`. Moreover, unless you have a very clear reason, you should declare the variable `name` as a local variable of the function `main`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string name;
  cout<<"<System>: Please enter your name"<<endl;
  getline(cin, name);
  cout<<name;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin` takes any whitespace (spaces, tabs, etc.) as a terminating character which is why you're only getting the first word.

Using `getline()` you can get the whole sentence until the return key is pressed:

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"<System>: Please enter your name"<<endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<name;
    return 0;
}
```